# How can I make this Bash variable work: myformat="--format=fuller --date=format:%Y-%m-%d T%H"

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

This is a question about how Bash handles word grouping and variable expansion. I will demonstrate the question with a very specific example:

```
bash$ git log --format=fuller --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d T%H"    # This works.

# Sample output:
commit aba22155684
Author:     SerMetAla
AuthorDate: 2018-04-12 T23
Commit:     SerMetAla
CommitDate: 2018-04-12 T23

    Here is the commit message.
```

I would like for this to work:

```
bash$ git log "$myformat"    # It should print the same stuff.
```

I don't know how to make it happen with just one Bash variable. Here is a working example with TWO variables:

```
# Define the two variables:
bash$ mypref="--format=fuller"
bash$ mydate="--date=format:%Y-%m-%d T%H"    # Note: No " after the colon.

# Now use it:
bash$ git log "$mypref" "$mydate"    # It works.
```

The problem is this: How can I possibly make this work with just one Bash variable? Is it possible?

**The Main Problem:**

```
git log --format=fuller --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d T%H"
                       |                       ^ This space is inside one argument.
                       |
                       ^ This space separates two arguments.
```

I would like to use a normal string variable. I do not want to use an array variable, I do not want to use `$'...'`, I do not want to use a function, I do not want to use an alias. When the string is immutable, and when it is not at the beginning of the command, it feels like it should be a Bash variable.

I could very easily solve this with a function in a manner that is fairly readable. I could solve it with other Bash tricks in a way that would be horrifying. I want to use a string variable.

Comment: Voted to close as **"unclear what you're asking"** because of "I could solve it with other Bash tricks in a way that would be horrifying". Please [edit] the question and at least name these tricks. First you explicitly rejected sane (non-horrifying) approaches, then you rejected my `eval`-based approach because "it falls in the category of horrifying Bash tricks, which I rejected as a group in my final paragraph. I can think of many such horrifying Bash tricks". So what are they? And what's left? You want to drive a nail, don't want a hammer and you complain other tools are flawed.

Comment: I would like to get to the store without walking, but I don’t want to use a vehicle.  I would like to win a game of chess, but I don’t want to move *that* piece or *that* one or *that* one …  What sort of answer are you expecting to a question that says “I want to do *X*, but I don’t want to use any of the *ways* of doing *X*.”?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common FAQ. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Briefly, the way to solve it is to put the arguments in an array.

```
myformat=("$mypref" "$mydate")
git log "${myformat[@]}"
```

As a very crude workaround, you could also use `printf` with the quoting format specifier:

```
printf -v myformat '%q %q' "$mypref" "$mydate"
git log $myformat
```

Comment: An array variable is the very first thing I rejected. It is the trivial solution, but I think they are rather hard to read and I am not using the array features, I am **always** going to call it as `"${myformat[@]}"`. Apart from being hard to read, that's a lot of typing. I can more easily use a function that returns a string, and twice as many Bash users are going to look at it and know what is going on, because functions are common.

Comment: Then put it in a function and put a comrent on top if you think your readers are unfamiliar with it. Have you looked into the alias facility in `git`? It basically lets you configure default options for `git` commands, or even define your own commands.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to use an array variable

You're rejecting a proper tool for the job. Well, you may try with `eval`:

```
$> foo='a "b c"'
$> printf "%s\n" $foo
a
"b
c"
$> eval printf '"%s\n"' $foo
a
b c
$>
```

In your case it would be like:

```
myformat='--format=fuller --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d T%H"'
eval git log $myformat
```

Comment: Recommended read regarding `eval`: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: @slhck I like that link. My favorite quote: `"eval" is a common misspelling of "evil"`. You are a helpful user. This answer with `eval` gets an A for effort but misses the point of my question, it falls in the category of horrifying Bash tricks, which I rejected as a group in my final paragraph. I can think of many such horrifying Bash tricks.

Comment: @SerMetAla Your question somehow falls in the category of horrifying; you are rejecting all the sane solutions already, without explaining why. This is often indicative of an [XY Problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)